# Batch Monitor status changes across all running services?

Tags: windows, service, monitor

In the event any (from all) running services on a windows machine stops, is it possible to catch this?

For reference, I currently have the following setup to monitor a specific service:

```
@echo off


set checkservice=myservice

echo Monitoring if %checkservice% service stops...


:checkServiceRunning
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "%checkservice%" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   ECHO %checkservice% stopped on %computername% at %date% %time% >>ServiceLog.txt
ECHO %checkservice% stopped on %computername% at %date% %time%


   PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
  )
)


goto checkServiceRunning

pause
```

For example, is there a windows log file that the stopping of a service would be reported in, and the log file could be checked repeatedly for the keyword eg 'stopped' or 'not running' ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Windows Services Monitoring Freeware

https://www.netwrix.com/windows_services_monitoring_freeware.html

it has the ability to monitor specified services and choose the option for the stopped one (Restart  Computer, Send an email alert, Start the service, Start a specified program)

Comment: Thanks I'll check that!